# How to add dynamic input fields and corresponding radio using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I have a html file and an AngularJS file (Bootstrap ui). Whenever I click on add button it should help me create a new td (input field) and 3 corresponding radio buttons as well. The following is my code but not sure how to implement that. I have tried to replace div with tr and td both doesn't work.

Html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.3.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/app.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="AlertDemoCtrl">
  <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
  <button type="button" class='btn btn-default' ng-click="addAlert()">Add Alert</button>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and JS file:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('AlertDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.alerts = [
    { type: 'danger', msg: 'Oh snap! Change a few things up and try submitting again.' },
    { type: 'success', msg: 'Well done! You successfully read this important alert message.' }
  ];

  $scope.addAlert = function() {
    $scope.alerts.push({msg: 'Another alert!'});
  };

  $scope.closeAlert = function(index) {
    $scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
  };
```

Please anyone can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$scope.alerts.push({type: 'newType', msg: 'Another alert!'});`

Answer (score 0):

The basic approach of AngularJs is:

- Template generated HTML, driven from values in your data model
- Use of custom directives, rather than jQuery, if you want to dynamically 
  manipulate the DOM.

In your case, a simple ng-repeat loop ought to suffice, generating a  td and three inputs for each element of a collection/array in your data model. When you click the button, you should update the number of elements in the collection.  If necessary, you can force a UI update with $apply.

Something like:

```
   <tr ng-repeat="cell in cells">
     <td>
       <label><input type="radio" ng-model="cell.value1" value="1">1</label<br/>
       <label><input type="radio" ng-model="cell.value2" value="2">2</label<br/>
       <label><input type="radio" ng-model="cell.value3" value="3">3</label<br/>
     </td>
   </tr>
```